# Mysql variable asignment failing in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am new to MySQL stored procedures. I made several assignments of a local variable named `sqlWhere`. The first 4 assignments work well. The others don't. From the 5th assignment `sqlWhere` becomes null. The assignments are as below:

```
IF datePosePrevueSup IS NOT NULL THEN
  SET SQL_WHERE_DATE_POSE_PREVUE_SUP = replace(SQL_WHERE_DATE_POSE_PREVUE_SUP, ':datePosePrevueSup', DATE_FORMAT(datePosePrevueSup, FORMAT_DATE)) ;
  SET sqlWhere = concat(sqlWhere, IF(sqlWhere = '', '', ' AND '), SQL_WHERE_DATE_POSE_PREVUE_SUP) ;
END IF ;
```

`sqlwhere` and uppercase variables have been declared with enough room...

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: they are always easy to debug with inserts into a table that has an auto_inc

Comment: print out the values of what you concat, one will be null

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to explain the steps to debug this, so you are more likely in the future to be able to debug this type of thing on your own.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat says:

> `CONCAT()` returns NULL if any argument is NULL.

Always keep this in mind. If any argument to `CONCAT()` is null, the whole string returned is NULL. Therefore if your `sqlWhere` becomes NULL, one of the arguments to `CONCAT()` is probably NULL.

The arguments to your call to `CONCAT()` are:

- `sqlWhere` from earlier code. You've tested that this is not NULL, I assume?
- `IF(sqlWhere = '', '', ' AND ')` This is pretty straightforward, it can only return the string constants, so they cannot be NULL.
- `SQL_WHERE_DATE_POSE_PREVUE_SUP`

Aha. Now we're getting somewhere. That last variable is the most likely culprit for being NULL. How is that variable's value set?

```
SET SQL_WHERE_DATE_POSE_PREVUE_SUP = replace(
    SQL_WHERE_DATE_POSE_PREVUE_SUP, 
    ':datePosePrevueSup',
    DATE_FORMAT(datePosePrevueSup, FORMAT_DATE)
) ;
```

Notice that `REPLACE()` also returns NULL if any of its arguments are NULL. The documentation doesn't mention this, but we can confirm it with some ad hoc tests:

```
mysql> select replace('foo bar baz', 'foo', null);
+-------------------------------------+
| replace('foo bar baz', 'foo', null) |
+-------------------------------------+
| NULL                                |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select replace(null, 'foo', 'FOO');
+-----------------------------+
| replace(null, 'foo', 'FOO') |
+-----------------------------+
| NULL                        |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select replace('foo bar baz', NULL, 'FOO');
+-------------------------------------+
| replace('foo bar baz', NULL, 'FOO') |
+-------------------------------------+
| NULL                                |
+-------------------------------------+
```

So now that we know this is a possibility, perhaps one of the arguments to your `REPLACE()` expression is NULL. What are the arguments?

- `SQL_WHERE_DATE_POSE_PREVUE_SUP` could be NULL, have you tested it?
- `':datePosePrevueSup'` is a string literal that is not NULL.
- `DATE_FORMAT(datePosePrevueSup, FORMAT_DATE)` may return NULL. Have you tested both of the variables?

We can confirm that `DATE_FORMAT()` also returns NULL if any of its arguments is NULL:

```
mysql> select date_format('2016-12-18', NULL);
+---------------------------------+
| date_format('2016-12-18', NULL) |
+---------------------------------+
| NULL                            |
+---------------------------------+

mysql> select date_format(null, '%x, %v');
+-----------------------------+
| date_format(null, '%x, %v') |
+-----------------------------+
| NULL                        |
+-----------------------------+
```

Hopefully this shows you some techniques for debugging this problem on your own in the future.